# Drupal breadcrumb truncated

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

My drupal breadcrumb stops at home link like:

```
home>
```

And not

```
home > title level1 > T level 2
```

In my template file `template.php` i have this:

```
function exceliance_breadcrumb($breadcrumb) {
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    return '<div class="breadcrumb"><span>'.t("You are here : ").'</span>'. implode(' › ', $breadcrumb) .'</div>';
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me why this seems to be truncated?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have an installed module, such as taxonomy breadcrumb, that is changing the $breadcrumb parameter.  You might also check the page.tpl.php file to ensure it isn't getting modified there.